# What is the length of the bar needed to represent 75 kilometers( in centimeters)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

In a bar graph, 1 centimeter represents 30 kilometers. What is the length of the bar needed to represent 75 kilometers( in centimeters)?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $1$ cm represents $30$ km, so $2$ cm reprsents $60$ km, and $3$ cm represents $90$ km; clearly the answer is between $2$ cm and $3$ cm. How many $30$ km segments can you fit into a $75$ km stretch of road? (The answer won’t be a whole number.) That’s the number of $1$ cm segments that you’ll need to represent that stretch of road on the map.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For these sorts of questions, ratios are useful. The centimeter to kilometer ratio is $1:30.$ You want $x:75.$

That is, $\dfrac{1}{30}=\dfrac{x}{75}$

Can you go on from here?